# What's the difference between RETRIEVE and RETREAT?

Tags: difference, vocabulary

What's the difference between "retrieve" and "retreat"?

They sound similar and many students think their usage is identical.

Comment: Please show what the dictionary research told you, and why you need more explanation.

Comment: These two words are completely unrelated, to a degree that “what’s the difference” makes no sense. What’s the difference between a tea pot and a maths exam? Doesn’t make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't related words. 'Retrieve' is transitive, and requires a direct object. 'Retreat' is not transitive and can't have a direct object.
I retrieve my lost pencil.
I retreat when the attack turns hopeless.